# Named Query Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, named

I have a query something like this

select emp from EMP emp where emp. empno like :emp_var  and  emp. empname like : empname_var and emp. empDate = :empdate_var

In the above query, all the three named parameters might not null or atleast one parameter will be not null and other might be null. In other words, I might retrieve only by empname or empDate or empno, or, by empname and empno and empdate.

How to achieve this in Hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check your values and add them to the `Criteria` as needed using `Restrictions`.

You can also look into using [`Example`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples).